# Serialize a dictionary of Django objects

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

Ok, so the problem I am facing is:
I know that there is a possibility to serialize "normal" python objects using:

```
json.dumps(something)
```

I know that you can serialize Django model objects using:

```
serializers.serialize('json', obj)
```

But how do I deal with mix of those: for example dictionary mapping ints to Django models? 
Is there any library that supports that?

This is generally what I am trying to do in my programm. Place django models in complicated data structures (lists, dictionaries) representing a schedule and pass them to front-end by JSON.

Comment: I would suggest looking at [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych , yep I studied their site, but from what I've seen they focus on serializing either normal objects or django model objects. But I take a closer look at their docs.

Comment: @Broccoli You need [ListAPIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview). It does what you want.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych, thanks for your resposne, but not really, because ListApiView simply returns objects from database. I need to put them into dictionary and numerate beforehand.

Comment: @Broccoli consider using DRF and extending/configuring one of the http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/ (ListSerializer or just BaseSerializer) to consume and produce a representation you need. DRF's serializers don't have to be tied to particular models or classes.

Comment: I strongly recommend you Django Rest Framework as well

Comment: Probably DRF solution is the best one available, but it has one downside: you need to specify a serializer for each datatype - at least as far as I understand it. I ended up writing my own generic serializer that seems to work well for different types and structures. No matter if I mix python and django object, put them in different structure etc. And it turned out to be quite simle.